# CallBack Function bind to another callback

Tags: javascript, ajax, object, callback

I have a problem with executing functions in right order.
I have First function to execute first. Inside this function I want to execute Second function and then Third function. However, because Second function has got AJAX callback function, Third function is executed before the Second's callback function has finished. Is there a way I can bind the callback function to the AJAX callback function? I have tried to illustrate the code below.I hope it makes sense what I want to achieve.

```
appObject.prototype.First = function(){
  this.Second(function(){
    this.Third();
  }.bind(this))
}

appObject.prototype.Second = function(callback){
  $.ajax(
  'webService.php',
    {
      type: 'POST',
      data: 'name=' + name,
      success: this.response.bind(this), //how to bind callback to callback
      error: errorAdd
    }
}

appObject.prototype.response = function(callback)
{
  callback(); //I would like to run the callback inside the AJAX callback
}
```

Comment: `this.response.bind(this, callback)`.

Comment: I have tried this, however I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function

It works if I call it inside the Second function, but once I passed it through the AJAX callback and call it in response function I recieve the above error

Comment: Then your actual code must be different.

Comment: I have found the error: in the callback I had it as
appObject.prototype.response = function(data,callback)

after I changed it to
appObject.prototype.response = function(callback,data)

Wrong order for parameters. Silly mistake

Thanks